# Ajax 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, rest

JS скрипт

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).on("input", function (address) {
            var addr = $(address.target).val();
            console.log(addr);

            var data = {
                'reduction': addr
            };

            return $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/location-service/dadata/reduction/',
                data: data,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    return response;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" name="input" id="input"/> <span id="errmsg"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

возвращает ошибку

```
POST http://localhost:8080/location-service/dadata/reduction/ 400 (Bad Request)
```

сам сервис сработает. тестирую через ARS

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

метод контроллера и сущность

```
@RequestMapping(value = POST, method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = "application/json",
            consumes = "application/json")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @ResponseBody
    public String postToDaDataServiceResponseAddress(@RequestBody DadataRequestBody request) {....}




@JsonAutoDetect
public class DadataRequestBody {
    public String reduction;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

data: JSON.stringify(data), вот так заработало)